# adding path to environnment variable is not working

Tags: variables, path, gradle, installation, m

I need help for installing gradle.
I am using Windows 7. What i did is:
1. I downloaded and unzipped gradle to C:\java\tools\gradle
2. I created a user variable GRADLE_HOME pointing to : C:\java\tools\gradle
3. Then i appended GRADLE_HOME to Path variable like this ...;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;
4. Finally i tryied gradle -v in cmd but it can't find it.
5. I also appended the full path C:\java\tools\gradle\bin to Path variable but it not working neither.

I don't understand what is wrong.
Please help. thx.

Comment: Did you open a new command prompt after editing the environment variables? Did you verify that `C:\java\tools\gradle\bin\gradle -v` works? It's not a Gradle specific problem.

Comment: Yes i did open a new command line and verify thaaat C:\java\tools\gradle\bin\gradle works but i could'nt resolve the problem.

Comment: Try running `echo %PATH%` in console window. This should give you a clue what went wrong.

Comment: Perhaps a spelling error then? I'd try things such as `echo %GRADLE_HOME%`, adding a backslash at the end of the path, editing system variables rather than user variables, executing `gradle.bat` rather than `gradle`, etc. It's nothing Gradle specific.

Comment: Resolved!  After having resorted my computer and trying to see if it works, i was disappointed. But then i appended full path to Path variable ..;C:\java\tools\gradle\bin; and at my surprise it worked!  
I am still trying to convince myself that i made a mistake the first try.

Comment: Probably best to delete the question as it doesn't add value for others.

Comment: It actually worked for me, I tried creating an environment variable 'GRADLE_HOME' and the I used '%GRADLE_HOME%\bin' in the path variable. But it didn't work. But later after some hair fall I edited the path variable to include the absolute path of the gradle folder and it worked. It should not have made a difference but it did. So I can disagree  because it worked for me I am wiser nevertheless thanks @velocity.